# GitHub: how to fork public repo to enterprise, edit enterprise version but still update with public fork

Tags: github

This is a follow up to the question [Is it possible to fork a public GitHub repo into an enterprise repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952033/is-it-possible-to-fork-a-public-github-repo-into-an-enterprise-repository/54600542)

I want to fork the public project `github.com/foo.git` and work on it on my enterprise server, under the name `github.enterprise.com/bar.git`. However, I want to keep them linked so I can pull any changes on the master. In other words, I am going to create some new codes and edits in my enterprise `bar.git`, but whenever the authors of `foo.git` update their master repo, I want to pull those changes.  So I followed the following steps.

1. Create an empty repository on `github.enterprise.com/bar.git`
2. Fork `github.com/foo.git` on my public GitHub account `github.com/MyPublic/foo.git`
3. Rename my public repo as to `bar.git` so it's `github.com/MyPublic/bar.git`
4. Create a bare clone of my new fork on my computer

   `git clone --bare https://github.com/MyPlublic/bar.git`
5. Change directories into the bare clones folder:

   `cd bar.git/`
6. Push the repository with the --mirror flag to my enterprise GitHub

   `git push --mirror https://github.enterprise.com/bar.git
    git remote set-url --push origin https://github.enterprise.com/bar.git`

Now I have the `bar.git/` directory on my computer, which is `BARE:master` and not an editable version of the repo. I have `bar.git` repos on my personal public GitHub.com account and on my Enterprise server. The next things I need to do are (1) clone the enterprise repo onto my computer and edit it; (2)  commit and push those changes to the enterprise repo; and (3) I also want to pull changes from the master `foo.git` repo when they happen.

I'm assuming I just do a standard clone, commit, and push for (1) and (2), i.e.

```
 git clone GitHub.enterprise.com/bar.git
 git commit
 git push
```

Is it actually possible to do #3? I'm thinking that in my computer's `bar.git/` directory, I execute

```
 git fetch -p origin
 git push --mirror
```

and then in the `bar/` directory, I execute a standard `git pull`?